# OKD request ETIMEDOUT - nodejs @ Production

Tags: node.js, promise, openshift, node-modules, connection-timeout

I'm stuck past few days. I've googled but nothings working to fetch me the results. The following code works onto my local m/c all results are fetched in 4ms. 
But then in production level, the following code throws gateway time out error. 
The application is deployed onto OKD (node module- **okd-api**) cluster where my application is one of its pods.

Here, I'm fetching all the pods

```
                   let fetchListarr=[];
                            aws_app.get('/List',  (req,res) =>
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Promise.all(promisesArray).then(values => {
                                    // do stuff with values here         
                                    res.send(values)
                                    })
                                    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
                                }
                                catch (e){console.log( e);}
                            });
                            var WMArr=[];
                            var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
                                    let config = {
                                    cluster:'my/url/to/openshift',
                                    user: 'user',
                                    password: 'password',
                                    strictSSL:  false
                                    };
                                    login(config)
                                                .then(okd=>{
                                                    okd.namespace('namespace').pod.watch_all(pods=>{
                                                            pods.map((v)=> {
                                                                    if(!WMArr.includes(v.object.metadata.labels.app))
                                                                        {                       let obj = {
                    TargetServiceName: v.object.metadata.labels.app,
                    Instance:
                    WMArr.lastIndexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app) ===
                    WMArr.indexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app)
                        ? 1
                        : WMArr.lastIndexOf(v.object.metadata.labels.app) + 1,
                    Status: v.object.status.phase
                };
                                                                                fetchListarr.push(obj);
                                                                        }
                                                                    WMArr.push(v.object.metadata.labels.app);
                                                                    });
                                                            })
                                                            setTimeout(function() {
                                                            resolve( fetchListarr);
                                                            }, 5000);
                                                    })
                                                .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
                                });
                            var promisesArray= [prom1];
```

Increasing the timeout won't do.

Can anyone please lemme know is the issue with the code?

Or as to where do I need to configure timeout setting (I'm new to  using OKD(openshift) to deploy the app)

Comment: Something appears to have gone wrong in the line ending `WMArr.indexOf(v.obje` and the following few lines.

Comment: Actually, the whole thing is disjointed and IMHO needs a workover before anyone could contemplate an answer. Happy to be proved wrong though.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 my bad I'd not pasted the code can you plz checknow